# How to make a method for that part of SAP-GUI script using Java and JNI?

Tags: java, activex, sap-gui, jacob

I have some methods already that I'm using for connecting to SAP GUI Scripting Engine using Java & JACOB library - I'm somehow unable to make one more method I'd like to use.

I am using "PoojaGugu"
https://github.com/PoojaGugu/SAP-GuiClient-Automation/blob/master/Java/library/src/main/java/com/library/generic/SAPGeneric.java
for studying the case.

I already tried copying some methods with editing some places in it, although it did not work. I can't provide you with examples.

So let me get to the actual problem here. I've got quite a lot of VBA code right now. I've been messing around with Java - just to get to know something else than making a macros in Excel. I'm using VB for connecting to SAP scripting engine, just to automate some work I've got. I can't make a proper method using Java&Jacob to do specifically this:

```
Set grid = session.FindById("wnd[0]/usr/cntlWC_INSP_CHAR/shellcont/shell")
grid.pressToolbarButton "&SORT_DSC"
```

That is how it looks like in my Excel macro, that one works. To simplify it:

```
session.FindById("wnd[0]/usr/cntlWC_INSP_CHAR/shellcont/shell").pressToolbarButton "&SORT_DSC"
```

It is pushing a button with id &SORT_DSC on SapGrid object. But using examples mentioned earlier I can provide you with a method that works on the very same display (transaction) on a very same "grid" scope:

```
 */SAPGuiGridSelectOrDeselectColumn
       * Objective - to  select or deselect the column  in the grid 
       * parameter  : partial id string , column name , SelectOrDeselect - Pass true to select column and false to Deselect the column
       * created by Venkata Siva kumar    
       */
      public void SAPGuiGridSelectOrDeselectColumn(String idstr, String column, boolean SelectOrDeselect) throws Exception
      {
         
          String id = getSAPObjectIDHelperMethod(getSession(), "ID", idstr, "", "");
          session = new ActiveXComponent(getSession().invoke("FindById",id).toDispatch());   
          if (SelectOrDeselect)
              Dispatch.call(session, "selectColumn", column);
         
          else
              Dispatch.call(session, "deselectColumn", column);
         
      }
      
      /*SAPGuiGridSelectOrDeselectColumn
```

This one is selecting columns from the table on that same page. To give you an image on how I do it in VBA:

```
grid.selectColumn "VARIANCE"
```

where a "grid" is previously mentioned path/object adress. It selects a column named "VARIANCE" withing the same SapGuiGrid scope that I want to press the %SORT button. That method works.

I wanted to make my method based on this one to click the button I mentioned earlier with no success (not only that method to be honest). How can I proceed?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This is what I came up with:

```
ActiveXComponent guiShellObject= new ActiveXComponent(Session.invoke("findById", "wnd[0]/usr/cntlWC_INSP_CHAR/shellcont/shell").toDispatch());
guiShellObject.invoke("pressToolbarButton", "&SORT_DSC");
```

That would replace:

```
session.FindById("wnd[0]/usr/cntlWC_INSP_CHAR/shellcont/shell").pressToolbarButton "&SORT_DSC"
```

Above example is self-explaining enough. I did not know how to do that untill I learned that I can pass on additional parameters with invoke method than only one.